# Access Spring Web MVC Exception Resolver from Spring Security Context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-security

I have a Spring Web MVC configuration with a `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` in it to handle some access exceptions:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I also have a Spring Security context configuration where I would like to handle some authentication related exceptions.  Currently, I have an `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` set up as follows:

```
<form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="exceptionMapper" ... />

...

<bean id="exceptionMapper" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler" >
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".CredentialsExpiredException">/resetPassword</prop>
            <prop key=".BadCredentialsException">/login?failure=true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I was thinking that it would be nice to consolidate these into a single exception handling configuration by moving the security mappings to the MVC configuration.  My problem is that I don't know how to tell Spring Security that I want `form-login`'s `authentication-failure-handler` to use the resolver.

I can't just add an `id` to `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` because 1) `authentication-failure-handler-ref` expects a Handler, not a Resolver, and 2) any beans that are defined in the MVC configuration don't seem to be visible from the security context...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To answer part 2) of your question, you can share bean definitions between configurations via the use of the `<import resource="..."/>` tag.

I'm not sure how successful you will be for part 1) (single exception resolver), because having looked at the API both classes are completely different - no shared interface. You may have to roll your own, using one of the classes as the platform and building the functionality of the other class into it.